# how to customize behavior of the delete operation in salesforce

Tags: trigger, delete

I am trying to customize the delete of a record in salesforce, I need that when the user wants to delete a record using the delete button in the CRM, somehow the record is not deleted, but a record field is updated, in my case I have a checkbox field that I need to set to "true" when the user hits the delete button.

How can I do it, I could not achieve it with apex triggers and nor with flows

Comment: just to clarify, should users be prevented from deleting these records so that another user can see which records should be deleted, or should they also be able to delete some of these records directly?

Comment: @CallumMacErlich No user should be able to delete those records. I just want that when any user tries to delete the record, then some process or something like that is launched and does nothing. In other words, when someone clicks the "Delete" button in the CRM, then nothing happens, only that a field of the record that was tried to be deleted is updated.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  That is a very strange use case.  Can't you remove the Delete permission from the object OWD in the user's profile?  Otherwise you will have to use  the `addError()` method in an Apex trigger to prevent the delete, and a separate async method to set the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that should be implemented for this.

First of all, you should remove the Delete permission from all users that do not require this. This is the best and most secure way of preventing any deletions. You can either check profiles manually or look at the [User Access and Permissions Assistant](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FeF99UAF) from Salesforce Labs on the AppExchange to check which users have this permission. On top of this, you would then need to add a Quick Action that would do the field update on the record when pressed.

For those users that you can't remove delete access from, you'll need to implement an Apex Trigger to add an error to all records that are trying to be deleted. This would be a fall back option just for where users require delete access due to permissions such as Modify All Data. The following example would prevent deletion of Account records for example:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before delete) {
    
    for(Account acct: trigger.old){
        if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isDelete){
            acct.adderror('You cannot delete the record'); 
    }
}
```

For the requirement to update the field on this, you're likely to require a secondary method to be fired asynchronously that will complete the update of the field after the error is added. This is due to the fact that adding an error to the record to be inserted will prevent any updates happening in the same transaction. For this, I'd recommend a Platform Event that you fire from the Trigger and a Platform Event Triggered Flow that does the field update.